# (Too?) simple model of a pn junction

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductors, pn-junction

I want to build a simple model of a pn junction in order to show high school students how it works. I am not looking for something precise, so I use really simple discretization and I discard units. I get satisfying results for equilibrium (no bias), but the asymmetry for forward and reverse bias does not seem to emerge from the model, which might be too simple.

My diode model is made of 2 slabs of p doped semiconductor (blue) and 2 slabs of n doped semiconductor (pink). Density of acceptors in the p region (N<sub>A</sub>) is equal to density of donors (N<sub>D</sub>) in the n region. The figure below shows the conditions at t = 0, when the p-region and the n-region come in contact. The total charge Q of each slab is 0 at t = 0.

[image: p and n regions come in contact at t = 0]

I suppose complete symmetry for holes and electrons (same diffusion constant D and same mobility μ). This implies that n<sub>1</sub> = p<sub>4</sub>, n<sub>2</sub> = p<sub>3</sub>, n<sub>3</sub> = p<sub>2</sub> and n<sub>4</sub> = p<sub>1</sub> at all subsequent times, which allows me to concentrate on holes only.

The equilibrium condition is that the total current of holes (diffusion + drift) must be equal to zero at each interface separating adjacent slabs.

The diffusion current of holes (I<sub>hD</sub>) at an interface is taken to be equal to the density of holes in the left adjacent slab minus the density of holes in right adjacent slab (taking D = 1). For example, the initial hole diffusion current in the interface between slabs #2 and #3 would be 10-0 = 10.

The drift current of holes (I<sub>hE</sub>) is the product of the density of holes, the mobility of holes and the electric field at the interface. Taking the slabs to be thin and very large, the electric field at an interface must then be equal to the total charge of slabs to the left of the interface minus the total charge of slabs to the right of the interface.

There is an equation for the total current for each of the 3 interfaces and an equation for conservation of charge (p<sub>1</sub> + p<sub>2</sub> + p<sub>3</sub> + p<sub>4</sub> = 20), since recombination is neglected . This allows me to find the values of the four unknowns p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>3</sub> and p<sub>4</sub>. I obtain the following results at equilibrium (for D = 1 and μ = 0.1):

[image: no bias (equilibrium)]

We can see that the total hole current at interfaces is zero. For example, for the interface between slabs #1 and #2:

E<sub>12</sub> = -1.52 – (-4.56 + 4.56 +1.52) = -3.04

Diffusion hole current: I<sub>hD</sub> = 9.77-7.19 = 2.58

Drift hole current : I<sub>hE</sub> = p<sub>average</sub>×μ×E<sub>12</sub> = 0.5×(9.77+7.19)×0.1×-3.04 = -2.58

Therefore I<sub>h</sub> = I<sub>hD</sub> + I<sub>hE</sub> = 2.58 – 2.58 = 0.

We can see that an electric field exists inside the diode at equilibrium. The built-in voltage V<sub>bi</sub> can be calculated from the values of the electric field: V<sub>bi</sub> = -(-3.04 -12.16 -3.04) = 18.24. We can also have a glimpse at a depletion region in slabs #2 and #3, which are farther from neutrality that slabs #1 and #4.

So far, so good. Now, let’s try to extend this simple model to see what happens when forward bias is applied to the junction by metal electrodes at both extremities.

For example, let’s suppose that forward bias causes a steady state (hole) current I<sub>h</sub>= 0.5 to the right. I find that the following density configuration is compatible with such a current:

[image: forward bias(steady state)]

Of course, in order to have steady state there must be a hole current I<sub>h</sub> = 0.5 at the interface between the left/right electrode and slab #1/#4. I suppose infinite conductivity for the electrodes (ohmic contact), so no electric field is needed to produce this total current (E<sub>01</sub> = E<sub>45</sub> = 0). Therefore the voltage across the diode must be V = -(0 -2.28 - 11.1 - 2.28 + 0) = 15.66.

Repeating the same procedure in reverse bias, for a hole current I<sub>h</sub> = -0.5, I obtain the following results, giving a steady state voltage V = -(0 -3.84 - 13.28 - 3.84 + 0) = 20.96 across the diode:

[image: reverse bias]

The following questions arise:

*Is there a relation between the steady state voltage, the equilibrium built-in voltage and the applied voltage?*

At first, I thought that the applied voltage corresponded to the difference between the two. If this is so, this calculation gives me an applied voltage of 18.24 - 15.66 = 2.58 for forward bias and 20.96 - 18.24 = 2.72 for reverse bias. As expected, the applied voltage is greater for reverse bias, but not as much as I had hoped!

*Does that mean that the current asymmetry in forward and reverse bias is due to hole-electron generation/recombination, which I neglected in my model?*

Comment: You seem to have defined the bias in terms of current Ih and then worked back the voltage difference required for that. Why not define the bias in terms of voltage and then work out the resulting current. It is possible that the reverse current for an ideal diode is zero and forcing it to be Ih=-0.5, might be creating some problems. If this is true, then, yes the assumption of absence of pair generation and recombination may be the reason for the existing results.